# *HELP* I cant figure this out

Tags: input, echo

> ssh $1 "$2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9" > blah

Is there a way to get like a 10th, 11th, 12th , etc.. option? Seems like I can only get 1-9..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `bash` you can use `${10}` - `${99}` as well.

Comment: Yes. But trying out would probably have been faster than asking here ;) Actually, the "correct" syntax for parameters is `${number}`, with `number` going from `0` to `99`. `$0` to `$9` are just (valid) shortcuts.

Comment: I would have tried it yes, But at the time I was driving down the road and wanted to ask before I forgot about it because I would not be able to get back on the box till Monday.. I do really appreciate your time and answers!